# Which version control + publishing solution

Tags: version-control, publish, rollback

I need a web application that can:

1. Track the files that have changed/been added between dev and a live site
2. Publish these changes/additions to a live site
3. Enable rollback to any point

I don't want to build it as I'm sure it's been done before.

What do you recommend and why?